# Interview Q: Reverse a word "Amazon" from string "I am working for Amazon"

Tags: java, string, reverse, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I am able to reverse a string. For example, I can reverse "reverse a string" to "esrever a gnirts".
I am trying to create a function that reverse a word from a sentence. I only want "Amazon" in reverse.Please help/suggest.

String = "I am working for Amazon" ;
Required output - "I am working for nozamA"

Please help/suggest. TIA

Comment: `split()` the string on whitespace.  Reverse the last element of the resulting array.  Reassemble.

Comment: I suggest you start with [`String.lastIndexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) -- `int p = s.lastIndexOf(' ');` -- then you know where the first part of the `String` ends, and the last word begins.

Comment: Use regex `replaceAll("\\bAmazon\\b", "nozamA")`.

Comment: Also in general, if you need to some complicated string manipulation, consider using `StringBuilder`.  It's mutable and can make some operations easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input :

```
String sentence = "I am working for Amazon";
String word ="Amazon";
```

with following step you can get desire output

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
String output = sentence.replace(word, reversed);
```